# C Substring matching

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to implement a regular expression type program, but using only letters, rather than metacharacters such as "*", ".", etc. I'm new to C so I'm struggling with this.

So for example, given a string of "a**bb**cdcd", and a search pattern b, the code will find every instance of b in the code, and seperate each instance with a space, So the output will look like "b b".

Another example is "abcbcbdbc" - given "bc", the program should match all the bc's in the input string, i.e "a**bcbc**bd**bc** so the output will be "bc bc bc".

I've been at this for several hours, not trying to use any functions of sorts, just implementing it in the main method, and was wondering if anybody could point me to the right direction?

This is what I've achieved so far, as part of my code. I've stored the input string and pattern into an array, and wish to store the output into an array called "match". :

```
int counter = 0;
int j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
{
     if (input_string[i] == search_pattern[j]) {
        j++; }
     else {
        j = 0; }
     if (j == patternLength) {
        j = 0;
        counter++;
     }
    }



print_string("output: "); 

// used to print the substrings

printf("%d",counter); //testing
   int x;
   int y;
   if (counter > 0) {
    for (x = 0; x < counter; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < patternLength; y++) {
        print_char(search_pattern[y]);
    }
    if (x < counter-1) {
        print_char('#');
     }
    }
   }
   else {
    print_string("No matches found");
   }
```

But it doesn't work when giving the input string "abcd" - giving "ad" prints "ad " when it should print nothing (perhaps an error message saying no matches were found?)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Can you give more information about matching and math arrays?

Comment: And you want the output to be "l l" right?

Comment: I've given some examples - i can give a few more:

Consider the string "hello" as an input, and "l" as a search pattern. I store "hello" in an array called input, and "l" in an array called pattern.

input[2] and input[3] == pattern[0], so I wish to print input[2] and input[3], and seperate them by a space, i.e output is "l l".

Now consider "ho" as an input, input[0] == pattern[0], but input[1] /= pattern[1], so nothing should be printed in this case, although both h and o are in the input string, they are not in the correct order, so thats "ho" won't be an output. Does this make sense?

Comment: So to clarify, a string should only be printed if the pattern is a substring of an input, but if the substring occurs more than once, then seperate this by a space, or any other seperator e.g. | would work too.

Comment: Maybe you should count the number of occurances of your substring and then create your new string as the number of occurances

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63287/discussion-between-ranifisch-and-tazman).

Comment: I don't see any string api calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            int count = 0;
            int pattern_index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == patternc[pattern_index])
                    pattern_index++;
                else
                {
                    pattern_index = 0;
                    if (input[i] == patternc[0] && patterncLength > 0)
                        pattern_index = 1;
                }
                if (pattern_index == patterncLength)
                {
                    pattern_index = 0;
                    count++;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I messaged you in chat.

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much, extremely appreciated. Learned alot from this after modifying it slightly :)

Comment: Hey, just one concern, the counter doesn't work for something like input = "hello", string = "lo", it should output lo,but it doesn't. I can't seem to find where the issue is and have walked through the program.

Comment: im on mobile now. ill check in an hour.

Comment: Please post your modified code, because with the code I posted above, it works perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63289/discussion-between-ranifisch-and-tazman).

Comment: I've been trying to edit this code to include the regex metacharacter "." - what this does is it matches any character in the string at all, so for example, input = "blah", given ".ah" as an input, the '.' matches an "l", and prints "lah". Or given "ababab" and ".b" returns "ab ab ab" (the '.' matches a). Do you have any suggestions on how this can be added to the current code?